# SQL Query Paremeters Add gives null reference exception

Tags: c#, mysql

**I'm getting null reference exception on this line:**

> cmd.Parameters.Add("@gross", DbType.Double).Value = gross_amount;

I have been trying this for a while now, but gross_amount is not NULL still getting me null reference exception in `Commission_Load_Setup();`

**Retrieving Values**

```
if (purchaseBillTableDataGridView[8, rowindex].Selected == true)
{              
  quantity = purchaseBillTableDataGridView[8, rowindex].Value.ToString();
}

if (purchaseBillTableDataGridView[9, rowindex].Selected == true)
{
    rate = purchaseBillTableDataGridView[9, rowindex].Value.ToString();
}

if (purchaseBillTableDataGridView[10, rowindex].Selected == true)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(quantity) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(rate))
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        gross_amount = double.Parse(quantity) * double.Parse(rate);
        purchaseBillTableDataGridView[10, rowindex].Value = gross_amount;
        load_commission_setup();

    }
}
```

This is the method to retrieve commissions.

```
string paisa;
private void load_commission_setup()
{
    SqlCeConnection conn = null;
    SqlCeCommand cmd = null;
    SqlCeDataReader rdr = null;
    try
    {
        conn =new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.sdf;Persist Security Info=False");
        conn.Open();
        //   int rowindex = purchaseBillTableDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1;
        //  gross_amount = double.Parse(purchaseBillTableDataGridView[10, rowindex].Value.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(gross_amount));
        //cmd.Parameters.Add("@gross", gross_amount);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@gross", DbType.Double).Value = gross_amount;
        cmd = new SqlCeCommand(@"SELECT Paisa FROM CommissionSetupTable WHERE=@gross BETWEEN FromRate AND ToRate;", conn);
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr == null)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                paisa = rdr["Paisa"].ToString();
            }
            rdr.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
        int rowindex = purchaseBillTableDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1;
        purchaseBillTableDataGridView[11, rowindex].Value = paisa;
    }
}
```

Thanks mohit, Now I'm getting only this error:

[image]

Comment: You really should be using `using` more for your reader and SqlConnection.

Comment: You set `cmd` to null at the start of `load_commission_startup()`. Of course it will give a NullReferenceExeption when you try do `.Add()`.

Comment: @Tvde1 my mind wasn't working :S... thanks... 

I'm getting error here `rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Using` to avoid forgetting to dispose of the resourses, especially when an exception is thrown, you can use the `using` syntax to automatically call dispose when you go out of the using statement's scope:

```
string paisa;
private void load_commission_setup()
{
    using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.sdf;Persist Security Info=False"))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(@"SELECT Paisa FROM CommissionSetupTable WHERE FromRate>=@gross AND ToRate<=@gross;", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@gross", DbType.Double).Value = gross_amount;
            using (SqlCeDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (rdr != null)
                    {
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            paisa = rdr["Paisa"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                    int rowindex = purchaseBillTableDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1;
                    purchaseBillTableDataGridView[11, rowindex].Value = paisa;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whereas the actual problem lies is stated by @Damith is to create the command first and then add the parameters.

Comment: I see... if we use using then we dont need to dispose of commands nice to know that.

Comment: your code says conn does not exist in the current context.

Comment: another error `using (SqlCeDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())`
connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: next error `There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 45,Token in error = = ]`

Comment: actually `@gross is the amount that I will check if it's between @FromRate and @ToRate`

Comment: try `WHERE @gross` instead of `WHERE=@gross`

Comment: Try to use `WHERE @gross >= FromRate AND @gross <= ToRate`

Comment: here is the thing.

I'm taking gross_amount calculated in datagridview and checking `this gross amount @FromRate and @ToRate in commissionSetupTable`

Comment: OMG :P FromRate and ToRate are the column names. then the query should be `WHERE FromRate>=@gross AND ToRate<=@gross;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129998/discussion-between-patrick-and-mohit-shrivastava).

Comment: unable to retrieve value paisa from CommissionSetupTable.

Comment: you made another typo mohit ;) thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

create command first

```
cmd = new SqlCeCommand(@"SELECT Paisa FROM CommissionSetupTable 
    WHERE=@gross BETWEEN FromRate AND ToRate;", conn);
```

then add the parameters

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@gross", DbType.Double).Value = gross_amount;
```

otherwise you are trying to add parameters to `null` command object

Comment: `next error There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 45,Token in error = = ]`

Comment: That is different issue.  stack overflow is direct Question and answer site, not forum. You can't add columns as parameters, here with between sql statement you have given `@gross` as column name and it is parameter. that will not work